# How to know whether there is a deleted neighborhood such than $f(x,y)\neq A$

Tags: real-analysis

This question comes from here, first we have a theorem below

> $\lim_{(x,y)→(x_0,y_0)}f(x,y)=A$ and there is a deleted neighborhood
>   such than $f(x,y)\neq A$ and  $\lim_{x\to A} g(x)=B$, then we have
>   $g(f(x,y))\to B$, when $(x,y)→(x_0,y_0)$.

how to know whether or not there is a deleted neighborhood such that $f(x,y)\neq A$?  I cannot find an easy way to know it, if this function $f(x,y)$ is complicated.

Comment: Do you have a particular pair of functions in mind? If $g$ is continuous then the deleted neighborhood condition is not necessary.

Comment: Well, if $f$ were continuous ad $(x,y)$ an isolated point of $f^{-1}(A)$ ...